# How to create a blurred/glow background for better text readability Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects, background, blur

I am a photoshop newbie, I am trying to add some transparent background for my text in order to make it more readable, but I don't know, how to create simple semi-transparent background with glowing edges (or how it is called).

Here is an example what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

So the idea is to create something like a smoke cloud, and place it as a background for a text layer to make it readable.

How can I get the desired result. I am interested how to create any shape and make it look like that so I could create background for any element.

Thanks. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Google for 'layer effects' and 'drop shadow'.

Comment: @Vincent thanks for the comment, but I have already tried this, there is not enough shadow

Comment: Then you'll have to try and tweak the effect's settings. Increase the choke, increase the size, increase the opacity, change the blending mode. Sorry, I'm pretty busy atm so I can't write a full answer :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw an ellipse shape layer using the `Ellipse Tool`.
2. Open `Window` → `Properties` and ensure the `Masks` tab is selected.
3. Adjust the feather radius.

The advantage of using this technique is that it can be edited at any time in the future. It also works for vector masks on layers and groups.

[image: Shape layer feather radius in Photoshop]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I solved my problem in the following way

1. Create any shape you want, in my case ellipsis.
2. Fill it with a color, in my case it is black.
3. Apply Filter-> Blur -> Gaussian Blur
4. Play with the layer opacity.

Thats all)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it.

1. Select the **Ellipse Tool** from the toolbar.
2. Now draw a horizontal oval shape by dragging across the canvas.
3. Right click on the shape layer and click on **Convert to Smart Object**.
4. On the menu bar, Click on **Filter** > Go to **Blur** >  and then click on **Box Blur...**
5. A new window opens up asking you set the blur radius(this will determine the amount of blurriness that will be added to that oval shape). Set the radius to **40 pixels** or **more**. And click OK.
6. Reduce the opacity(from the opacity field just above the layers panel) to **50%**(or any percentage that suits you).
7. Now click on the **text tool(Horizontal or Vertical Type tool)** from the toolbar and click anywhere on the canvas. This will create a new Text Layer. Type anything you want here.
   [image]
8. If the text goes outside the oval shape just hit "**Ctrl+T**" on your keyboard, it will activate the transformation controls. Now just stretch the oval shape so that it covers the entire text.

Comment: That's kinda exactly just what's in the other answer... Answered by OP him/herself...